# Issue with logic when looping in vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I've created a particularly long vba macro to edit a large spreadsheet of data for me instead of doing it myself thousands of times. The code for the actual editing works fine, however, when I add in the first if statements and first while loop to make it loop through the whole spreadsheet, I get a runtime error 1004. I'm new to vba but I'm pretty sure there is an error in my logic rather than the code itself. I've marked which lines of code cause the error when added.

```
  Sub RCFS()

Dim ProfCtr As String
Dim Year As String
Dim Amount As Currency
Dim Period As Long
Dim S2FreecellH As Long
Dim ProfCenCellH As Long
Dim FreeCellClone As Long
Dim Clone2 As Long
Dim Clone3 As Long


Dim y As Long ' placeholder 2
y = 1

S2FreecellH = 3
ProfCenCellH = 2
AmountH = 2
PeriodH = 2
YearH = 2


ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
Year = Cells(YearH, 7)
Amount = Cells(AmountH, 8)
Period = Cells(PeriodH, 6)

'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
While IsEmpty(Cells(ProfCenCell, 4).Value) = False
```

> Everything fine until this while loop (above) and if statement (below). The rest works fine without these 2 statements but I need it to loop through the whole spreadsheet.

```
If Cells(ProfCenCell, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value Then

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value = ProfCtr
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 5).Value = ProfCtr
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 9).Value = ProfCtr

FreeCellClone = S2FreecellH 'setting clones
Clone2 = S2FreecellH
Clone3 = S2FreecellH

For x = S2FreecellH + 1 To S2FreecellH + 12
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2).Value = y 'Creating 1 to 12 numbering in column 1
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 6).Value = y 'Creating 1 to 12 numbering in column 2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 10).Value = y 'Creating 1 to 12 numbering in column 3
S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 1
y = y + 1
Next x

While Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone, 1).Value = Cells(YearH, 4).Value 'Loop to input all amounts
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone + Period, (((Year Mod 11) * 4)) - 1).Value = Amount 'Calculation on post year to select correct column to post amount in

PeriodH = PeriodH + 1
AmountH = AmountH + 1
YearH = YearH + 1

Year = Cells(YearH, 7)
Amount = Cells(AmountH, 8)
Period = Cells(PeriodH, 6)
Wend

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone + 1, 3), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 3)))
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone + 1, 7), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 7)))  'Creating sums for all 3 columns
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 11) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone + 1, 11), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 11)))

For Z = Clone2 + 1 To Clone2 + 12  'creating intitial percentage values
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 4).Value = Format((Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 3) / Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 3)) * 100, "%0.00")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 8).Value = Format((Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 7) / Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 7)) * 100, "%0.00")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 12).Value = Format((Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Z, 11) / Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 11)) * 100, "%0.00")
Next

For q = Clone3 + 1 To Clone3 + 12 'creating final percentage values
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(q, 13).Value = Format(((Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(q, 4) + Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(q, 8) + Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(q, 12)) / 3) * 100, "%0.00")
Next q

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH + 1, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(FreeCellClone + 1, 13), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 13)))




Else
ProfCenCell = ProfCenCell + 1
End If
    '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Loop these Loops
S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 3
y = 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: hmm looks interesting ill check it out. Vba is kind of annoying cause of the lack of indents I agree.

Comment: `Dim Year As String`   Don't use the name of preexisting functions as a variable name.  You should also consider using `With Worksheets("Sheet2")` to replace the 38 `Worksheets("Sheet2")` references.   At some point `(((Year Mod 11) * 4)` will probably equal 0, which would cause an Object defined error.

Comment: Well the TAB key does wonders for manual indentation... don't blame the language for that.

Answer (score 3):

You never set a value for `ProfCenCell`, hence it has default value `0`. Then, you use `Cells(ProfCenCell, 4)` which is in your case `Cells(0, 4)` and that 0 makes a problem.

Comment: Oh man can't believe I missed that, it's supposed to be ProfCennCellH not ProfCenCell. I fixed it and it got rid of the runtime error but now its giving me an overflow error instead.

Comment: @user392500 Can you put `Option Explicit` at the top of the page and recompile?